# How to know when the database is ready in Django?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-orm, django-signals

I need to do stuff as soon as the database is ready in Django. Specifically, I need to perform some calculations on values from db and fill the results into cache.

Since django 1.7, the [application registry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/) makes it easy to know when an app or models are ready to be used. You can write:

```
from django.apps import apps

if apps.ready:
    do_some_stuff()
```

But I found out that the models being ready does not mean the database can be queried. Django doc's says:

> Although you can access model classes as described above, avoid
>   interacting with the database in your ready() implementation

I tried to hook up to the `post_migrate` event. It works if I'm rebuilding the database (e.g launching the test suite), but does not if I'm just using an existing db (e.g using `runserver`).

Is there a way to know if the database is fully available in Django >= 1.7?

Comment: I want to understand your use-case properly (specifically why the runserver is important).  You are populating a cache on both post-migrate tasks and spin-up tasks and looking for the proper hook when to.  These are heavy cache tasks (or tricky atomicity) and hence you want to insure once-only execution.  Is this a fair restatement of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I use also the post_migrate signal. (as : https://github.com/mrjmad/django_badgificator/blob/master/badgificator/apps.py).

I realize by reading your question it does not work with 'runserver' ...

Comment: So did you find a solution that works in both cases?

Comment: Are you try with "connection_created" signal ?

Comment: Yep, also does not work, see other answers and comments.

Comment: I have not been clear in my last answer. If you are using post_migrate when you have migration and connexion_created when you do not have one, is that it might work?  

To find out if you have migration, a simple but ugly way, that is to test whether there is the word "migrate" in the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can try hooking up a receiver for the [connection_created](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/signals/#connection-created) signal.

Comment: This signal is emitted as soon as django connects to the database, but before it runs all the migrations, so it won't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you are trying to do, you want to fill the cache with data from DB when you start runserver. Since in production, runserver won't reload you will fill your cache only once until you restart the server (and I'm not even sure that gunicorn would behave the same way as runserver for this.)

So you probably have another way to update your cache using celery or something similar after the startup? Why not just use the same way to perform the first run?

Answer (score 0):

You could setup your code in the wsgi.py file after the application is imported and called, like so:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

print MyModel.objects.all()[0:5]
# Setup your startup code here since you already have access to your models
```

I found this answer based on this link:
[Entry point hook for Django projects](http://eldarion.com/blog/2013/02/14/entry-point-hook-django-projects/)

Comment: Ok, it does not completely answers the question, but the link you provided guided me to the correct approach. Thanks.

Comment: @ThibaultJ Hey how did you solve this issue ? I have a similar issue

Comment: @SyedAmmarMustafa Sorry, this comment is more than four years old. I don't remember and I'm sure there are better ways to do it now anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Any code in `project/__init__.py` will run on startup after the Database is ready but before any views/urls can be accessed, so just put some code in `__init__.py` and it will run as you expect. `post_migrate` might be redundant because as far as I'm aware, you can't run migrations with the app running, If you absolutely need it, just have a function that runs on startup and when the signal is called.

Comment: Unless I did not understand your answer, this is simly not true. Code in __init__.py will run as soon as the python interpreter imports the package, so before anything else.